# Can we configure Approval Process in Bitbucket CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: bitbucket, devops, bitbucket-pipelines

I am currently doing Research on Azure DevOps & Bitbucket Pipeline for implementing a CI/CD Pipeline for our application.
I have found that in Azure DevOps, we have the option of adding multiple users which would have to approve before pipeline proceed further.
I have not found anything same regarding bitbucket pipeline, Only thing I have found is that pipeline can be trigger manually or automatically.

Is there a way in Bitbucket Pipeline to configure Approval Process?

Answer (score 0):

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: ManualApproval
        image: atlassian/pipelines-awscli
        trigger: manual
        script:
          - echo "Manual Trigger required to run this pipeline"
```

The above code should do. Or Refer: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/approvals?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thank you @pradeep for your answer, but this is not what I am looking for.

I want to know whether I can specify a user who needs to approve a pipeline before proceeding further.
A manual trigger can be used by anyone, I want only specific people to approve or reject using bitbucket pipeline.

Comment: @TanmaySingh, looks like a solution was not found. I am/was looking for the same. From what I can see, you can only allow those types of approvals for merges to a particular branch.